# Laravel 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' how to find the URL that is causing the issue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a CMS which uses quite a large number of ajax calls. There are no visible issues, but often when I look in Laravel's log file, I see a similar rambling mess of an error message about a 'NotFoundHttpException', presumably due to one of my api calls not finding the correct route.

I love Laravel, but my god, this has got to be one of the most unhelpful errors I have ever seen. There are references there to files deep within Laravel's core which I have no reason to ever touch nor care about. If this is a routing problem (which it ostensibly is) then all I really want to know is what the URL is that is causing the problem.

Is there any way of finding out which is the problem route, or any way of re-configuring the error reporting to tell you?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to configure Laravel's error logging in such a way, but you can do it by yourself.

The error logging happens in `app/start/global.php`. There you have the "Application Error Handler". You can easily add an if statement and log your own message, including the actual URL that has been called.

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    $message = $exception;

    if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException){
        $message = 'URL '.Request::url().' not found - '.$exception;
    }
    Log::error($message);
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for- this will be a mandatory piece of custom code for all new Laravel installations for me from now on. Many thanks!

Comment: Incidently, I am now able to see that the errors I was getting relate to a couple of small gif icons that weren't being found, which I am now able to remedy. Very useful.

Comment: You're welcome. I was quite surprised myself that Laravel doesn't log the URL already. Because as you said, without it, the error is useless.